# Отправка JSON из мобильного приложения и получение на PHP сервере

Tags: jquery, json, php, javascript

Я отправляю с мобильного приложения данные запросом

```
$("#sendRoute").live('click', function(){ 
      routeJSONString = JSON.stringify(trackCoords);
  $.ajax({
  url: "localhost:3000/addRoute",
  type: "POST",
  data: { 
    route : routeJSONString,
    timeInMinutes: final_time_m,
    timeInSeconds: final_time_s_rounded,
    averageSpeed: aver_speed_km_h_rounded,
    distance: total_km_rounded      
  },
  dataType: "json"
 });
});
```

И мне нужно как то их получить на PHP сервере, как это можно сделать?
P.S. url: "localhost:3000/addRoute" это рыба, URL на который будут посылаться данные другой

Comment: Читать "Программирование на PHP" до полного просветления..
Потому что вопрос звучит как "Пацаны, сделайте мне зашибись"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$route = $_POST['route'];
$timeInMinutes=$_POST['timeInMinutes'];
$timeInSeconds=$_POST['timeInSeconds'];
$averageSpeed=$_POST['averageSpeed'];
$distance=$_POST['distance'];
```

[Тут многое узнаете интересного, в том числе и решение вашего вопроса](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/)